# Desktop windows show an outline after being moved

Tags: windows-7

When I used to drag a window with my mouse it moves with the mouse, but when I release the mouse the window stopped there. Now, however, it will show the outline of the window when I am dragging it, then I release the window and it stops, but there is an outline as well. Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean that the window when dragging looks like that, and you want it to look like you are dragging the whole window around, not just the outline of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting in windows "show window contents while dragging", is what you are looking for. When this is on, the whole window moves, which is what you want.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/75059-show-window-contents-outline-while-dragging.html

Comment: yea it work. But it is enabled...i disable it  and enable it, it work fine now